# Syntax for parameter pack in templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class which I want to give a parameter pack type method, like this:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {
public:
    template<class U>
    add(U u) {}

    template<class U, typename... Args>
    add(U u, Args... args) {
    }
};
```

Note that `T` and `U` are always the same type.

My question is simply: Is it possible to refer directly to `T` instead of `U` in this instance? What I have works, but it would be clearer what the intention is if I referred to `T` directly.

Comment: You mean like `template<typename... Args> add(T t, Args... args)`?

Comment: what do you mean with "refer to `T` directly"? In your example `T` and `U` arent necesarrily the same type

Comment: Yeah I meant that they are the same type, but forgot to clarify that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want this:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {
public:
    add(T t) {}

    template<typename... Args>
    add(T t, Args... args) {
    }
};
```

Note that this is different from what you had: your original code accepted *any* type as the first argument of `add`, while this code only accepts a `T`.

Comment: Thanks, that was simple. I could have sworn I tried this already before asking and got an error, but obviously some detail was wrong in my version.